Reference for function space definition of geometric realization of abstract simplicial complex
The following is described on Wikipedia as one way to define the geometric realization of an abstract simplicial complex $K$:

The construction goes as follows. First, define $|K|$ as a subset of $[0,1]^S$ consisting of functions $t: S \to [0,1]$ satisfying the two conditions:
$$
 \{ s \in S : t_s > 0 \} \in K
 $$
$$
 \sum_{s \in S} t_s = 1
 $$
Now think of the set of elements of $[0,1]^S$ with finite support as the direct limit of $[0,1]^A$ where $A$ ranges over finite subsets of $S$, and give that direct limit the induced topology. Now give $|K|$ the subspace topology.

Here $S$ is the vertex set of $K$.
This post and answer give some additional context and explanation/motivation for this definition, which I found helpful.
Question: The Wikipedia article gives no source for this definition, and neither does the linked post. I assume it is "standard" but if so, there should be plenty of places to find this definition. Where can I find this definition being given and/or used? Does it go by any other names or descriptions? (Wikipedia just calls it the "Topological definition")
What I tried: I checked some standard algebraic topology books (Munkres, Hatcher, Bredon), but didn't find it in any of those. Google searches for various descriptions of this definition, using, e.g., the keywords "geometric realization" + "function space" or "functions to [0,1]", etc. didn't turn up much either.

You can find a discussion of the various ways of topologizing the geometric realization of a simplicial simplex in Tammo tom Dieck, Algebraic Topology, Section 8.1.

Precisely the type of resource I was looking for, thank you.

Also Chapter III in Spanier's "Algebraic Topology" is a nice source.
